# Recognizing a subtype of Drum 'n' Bass

Tags: identify-this-genre

Can someone tell me what specific subtype of [Drum 'n' Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_and_bass) this track is?

- [*Unreal Tournament '99 GOTY Soundtrack - Nether Animal*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbn_dH9nz6o) composed by [Michiel "M.C.A." van den Bos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michiel_van_den_Bos)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [Neurofunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurofunk), which is an evolution from the earlier (and somewhat more minimalist) [Techstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techstep) genre. Recognizable by a dark, sci-fi, atmospheric sound. Similar music is made by artists like [Maztek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maztek), [BTK](https://eatbrain.net/btk), [Optiv](http://darkdnb.com/optiv), [Gridlok](https://soundcloud.com/gridlokdnb).